# ASP.NET Core Distributed Redis Cache: Disconnect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'am using Redis cache as distributed cache in ASP.NET app.
It works until Redis server becomes unavailable and the question is:
How to properly handle disconnection issues?

Redis is configured this way (Startup.cs):

```cs
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(...)
```

Option AbortOnConnectFail is set to false

Injected in service via constructor:

```
...
private IDistributedCache _cache

public MyService(IDistributedCache cache)
{
  _cache = cache;
}
```

When Redis is down the following code throws an exception (StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on 127.0.0.1:6379/Subscription ...):

```
var val = await _cache.GetAsync(key, cancellationToken);
```

I don't think that using reflection to inspect a connection state inside _cache object is a good way. So are there any 'right' options to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check [Polly Project](http://www.thepollyproject.org/). It has Retry/WaitAndRetry/RetryForever and Circuit Breakers that can be handy. So you can catch that `RedisConnectionException` And then retry or fallback to other method.

You have Plugin for Microsoft DistributedCache Provider.

Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I thought about try/catch solutions, but I hoped there is some more elegant way.

Comment: Polly is robust and looks like a elegant way to solve connection failure. And you can wait and retry again after connection fails, and that's a good thing, or you can fallback to specific action.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why is your Redis server becoming unavailable? And for how long? You should minimize these kinds of situations. Do you use Redis as a service from AWS i.e. ElasticCache? If so you can configure it to promote a new Redis slave /read-replice server to become a master if the first master fails.

> To improve fault tolerance and reduce write downtime, enable Multi-AZ with Automatic Failover for your Redis (cluster mode
> disabled) cluster with replicas. For more information, see Minimizing
> downtime in ElastiCache for Redis with Multi-AZ.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/AutoFailover.html

Apart from that, a fallback solution to an unresponsive Redis server would be just to retrieve the objects/entities that your a caching in Redis from the database if the Redis server is down. You can retry the Redis call two times with 5 seconds between each retry and if the server is still down you should just query the database. This would result in a performance hit but it is a better solution than throwing an error.

```
T val = null;
int retryCount = 0;

do 
{
      try 
      {
          val = await _cache.GetAsync(key, cancellationToken);
      }
      catch(Exception ex) 
      {  
         retryCount++;
         Thread.Sleep(retryCount * 2000)
      }
 }
 while(retryCount < 3 && val == null);
 
 if (val == null) 
 {
    var = call to database
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't matter why redis may become unavailable, the point is that when it is down the app itself should operate despite of a lack of performance.

Comment: Well, you have to solutions: either query the cached object/data from the database when Redis server is down or try to implement a failover functionality similar to the one in the ElasticCache AWS service i.e. read the data from a read replica if the primary server is down.